# Ruby/Rvm sudo install on Linux desktop, terminal does not get Ruby tools in PATH

Tags: ruby, rvm

`ruby` / `rvm` and associated tools are not being added to `PATH`, after installing RVM as sudo.

This problem is only happening on desktop Linux terminal (e.g. Linux Mint), and not through an ssh terminal.

#### Installation

I have installed RVM using the following commands (using sudo so that the tools are installed globally for all users):

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby=2.7.0

#  Finally, add "rvm" group to all users who need Ruby AND reboot.
```

#### Desktop Terminal Application - DOES NOT WORK

When I open a terminal application, inside the desktop, the **`PATH` variable does not contain Ruby/Rvm**!

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

#### SSH Terminal - WORKS!

If I ssh to the Linux system, then the `PATH` will contain the correct Ruby/Rvm paths:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

---

Some experiments inside the desktop terminal:

#### (1)  Manually sourcing:

A workarounds, manually sourcing the rvm script:
If I `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` then Ruby/Rvm will be added to the PATH correctly (but only for this one terminal instance).

#### (2)  Trying my own profile.d script:

If I create a dummy file `sudo vi /etc/profile.d/testaddtopath.sh`, which has just one line:

```
PATH=$PATH:testpath
```

then this will modify the $PATH after reboot, in both the desktop's terminals and through ssh.

---

#### Questions

I guess the big question is... why is the `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` file not working as I would expect inside the desktop?

Is there a different way to install RVM and Ruby globally (for all users), and have the tools be ready and available to all users?

Comment: Your question has two unrelated questions. Why isn't `profile.d/rvm.sh` working vs. is there a different way to install RVM globally. Because they're unrelated your question is off-topic as multiple questions must be closely related. Also, the [RVM site](https://rvm.io/) is THE authoritative source for answering RVM questions, especially about installing as root using sudo. Its [support page](https://rvm.io/support) would be a good resource.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan, I will look at raising the question in RVM support.


I don't want to give too much opinion, I might be wrong for many reasons; e.g. I think this has something to do with non-/login shell, but not sure, so I shouldn't pollute the question with wrong assumptions, but rather just give the facts.


Maybe my question is simply about `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and why/whether it should work.


Installing RVM globally (or for "Multi-User") is known, as I've followed the instructions from [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).  So, I have no question on installation.